# Template not loading under component design

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

I am trying to make a single page application while using components since my company will be moving to using components in the future and I am trying to follow the angular-phonecat tutorial. The problem I'm having is that for some reason in my app.config.js file, the template for the home page is not being recognized (the home-page portion) and I can't figure out why. If I replace that with a simple string of 'hello', it displays just fine, so it has to be somewhere in my components but I can't track down why it's not recognizing it.

Relevant code:

app.config.js:

```
angular.
module('newSpa').
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
    function config($locationProvider, $routeProvider){
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

        $routeProvider.
            when('/home',{
            template: '<home-page></home-page>'
        }).
            when('/contacts', {
            template:'<contacts></contacts>'
        }).
            otherwise('/home');
    }]);
```

app.module.js:

```
angular.module('newSpa', [
'ngRoute',
'homePage',
'contacts'
```

]);

home-page.template.html:

```
<div>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
</div>
```

home-page.module.js:

```
angular.module('homePage', []);
```

home-page.component.js:

```
angular.module('homePage').component('homePage', {
templateUrl: 'home-page/home-page.template.html',
controller: 'homeCtrl'
```

});

controllers.js:

```
angular.module('homePage', []).controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.message = 'hello';
}]);
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="newSpa">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SPA Contacts</title>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="app.config.js"></script>
    <script src="home-page/home.module.js"></script>
    <script src="home-page/home.component.js"></script>
    <script src="contacts/contacts.module.js"></script>
    <script src="contacts/contacts.component.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

My app.config.js file is in the root "app" directory, and my home files are all in the "/app/home-page" directory. Link to angular-phonecat: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03

Comment: Errors in console?

Comment: No errors, that's why I can't figure this out. Everything loads fine, just the template isn't being recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my previous solution was still incorrect. The real solution is that my controller was redefining the 'home' module because I had square brackets. Here is the old controller:

```
angular.module('homePage', []).controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.message = 'hello';
}]);
```

So as you can see, when I have square brackets in the module definition, I am redefining the module, thereby overwriting all previous definitions of the module. When I removed those brackets:

```
angular.module('homePage').controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.message = 'hello';
}]);
```

Everything displays properly. So the issue was I was making a new module with just the controller, so it didn't have the  template to push to the view to update.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have named your component 'home' but are using 'home-page' in your template.

Comment: Yes, here is the remainder of what I was working with at the end of the day. updated for the correction

Comment: Couldn't edit previous comment, so I'll add that it still didn't work under that namespace.

Comment: These things always happen to me. Inattention from me.